# Request book contains all functions with their series representations

Tags: reference-request

Is there any book that contains all functions with their series representations like this site http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/06/ShowAll.html?

Comment: All functions? That's gonna be a long book.

Answer (score 1):

The standard hardcopy reference is *[Handbook of Mathematical Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abramowitz_and_Stegun)* by Abramowitz and Stegun, which is now also [available online](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/).

Series for logarithmic function are on [page 68](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_68.htm).